# Field inheritance

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

I have next code. Why field userId is invisible in InheritUser?

```
class User{
    private $userId;

function User($userId){
    $this->userId = $userId;
}

    function getId(){
        return $this->userId;
    }
}

class InhreritUser extends User{
    function someFunc(){
            echo $this->userId; // nothing
    }
}
```

someFunc returns nothing:

```
$inheritUser = new InheritUser(1);
$inheritUser->someFunc();
```

Comment: Because it's private. That's what private does. If you want visibility only in inheriting classes, mark is as protected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the point of the `private` keyword. If you use `protected` this will work.

See: http://php.net/language.oop5.visibility

Also, that code would have thrown an error, if you didn't turn off errors in PHP (bad idea during development).

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

A class member needs to be protected for it to be visible to a subclass. Private means that subclasses *won't* be able to see it.

```
protected $userId;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's private. Make it protected instead.

Private fields are accessible to the class only. Protected fields are available to subclasses too.